# Which is the best way to process big json & replace specific values?

Tags: json, go

I have a big json (30mb) which contains "title" fields in different objects , structure of json is unknown.

Known only that json contains keys "title" and string value of this key must be translated into another.

```html
{
    "data1" : {
        "title" : "alpha",
        "color" : "green"
    },
    "data2" : {
        "someInnerData1" : {
            "title" : "beta"
            "color" : "red"
        },
        "someInnerData2" : {
            "someArray" : [
            {
                "title" : "gamme",
                "color" : "orange"
            },
            {
                "title" : "delta",
                "color" : "purple"
            }
            ],
            "title" : "epsilon"
        }
    }
}
```

Replace example
"alpha" -> "Α"
"beta" -> "B"
etc..

Which the best way achieve that in Golang , without decoding into struct ?

**P.S.** Json is received from network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a streaming JSON decoder like [megajson](http://github.com/benbjohnson/megajson/scanner):

```
// Transform 'title' strings into Title case
func TitleizeJSON(r io.Reader, w io.Writer) error {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    r = io.TeeReader(r, buf)

    s := scanner.NewScanner(r)
    var prevTok int
    var prevPos int
    wasTitle := false
    titleField := []byte("title")
    for {
        // read the next json token
        tok, data, err := s.Scan()
        if err == io.EOF {
            return nil
        } else if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        // calculate the position in the buffer
        pos := s.Pos()
        off := pos - prevPos

        switch tok {
        // if this is a string
        case scanner.TSTRING:
            // if the previous string before a : was 'title', then
            // titlelize it
            if prevTok == scanner.TCOLON && wasTitle {
                // grab the first part of the buffer and skip
                // the first ", the titleize the rest
                data = buf.Bytes()[:off][1:]
                copy(data, bytes.Title(data))
                wasTitle = false
            } else {
                wasTitle = bytes.Equal(data, titleField)
            }
        }

        // now send the data to the writer
        data = buf.Bytes()
        _, err = w.Write(data[:off])
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // reset the buffer (so it doesn't grow forever)
        nbuf := make([]byte, len(data)-off)
        copy(nbuf, data[off:])
        buf.Reset()
        buf.Write(nbuf)

        // for the next go-around
        prevTok = tok
        prevPos = pos
    }
}
```

This should do the titleizing on the fly. The one case I can think of where it will have a problem is if you have a really really big string.

Comment: Thanks , its what i need

Answer (score 0):

I would make a struct that implements the `io.Reader` interface, and use that reader as a translation ground: you can use it to get you JSON input chunk by chunk, and detect when you are on a key that need to be changed, so translate it on the fly.

Then, you just have to use a `io.Copy` to read the whole file into another.

See the [text.transform](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/transform) package dependency graph for examples…

Comment: In that way how can i parallelize using goroutine ?

Comment: Using a goroutine for that kind of thing sounds like a bad idea: you can't really multiplex the reading of a file...

Comment: Idea is : default buffer size about 1kb, **1)** Set begin offset to M **2)** move pointer to offset M+1024 , **3)** read rune if its not json delimeter move forward to closest delimeter and find it on N position, **4)** call goroutine func with begin offset (M), end ofsset (1024+N),  repeat steps.